# How to apply slide master to transplanted slides

Tags: powerpoint

I transplanted some slides from one presentation to another.  I noticed that the transplanted slides do not have a key logo, even though the logo exists on the Master Slide of the destination presentation.  Web searching hasn't revealed how to re-apply the Master Slide to the imported slides.  While it seems unbelievable to me, I am beginning to wonder whether this simple function is simply not supported?

I am using Powerpoint 2007 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasted slides will assume the existing slide master and layout only if all these conditions are met:

- The new slide layout must have the same **name** as the old one. This is easy, you can set this in the program interface.
- The new slide layout must be the same **type** as the old one. Slide layouts include a layout type in the second line of the layout XML, if the layout is one of the Microsoft standard layouts. If that layout has been copied, or a new layout has been inserted, its type will be Custom. This layout property can be read and set with VBA.
- The new slide layout must have the same **number of placeholders** as the old one. Other shape types don't matter.
- The new slide layout must have the same **types of placeholders**. Normally, this and the number of placeholders can be determined from the Selection Pane.
- The placeholders on new and old layouts must have matching **idx** numbers. This requires XML hacking to read and set, as there is nothing in the user interface or standard VBA that allows you to read or set the idx number of a placeholder.

Comment: Thanks, John.  I ended up using the Neaderthal approach.  Straight copy and paste slide elements onto new slides.  One. Slide. At. A. Time. Your answer sheds light on to what is required to avoid the Neanderthal solution.  Both approaches being very non-ideal.